# Curl returning blank api

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, local

I've this function to curl an url (in my codeigniter website):

```
private function _curl_download($Url){

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://local.mywebsite.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

This is suppose to return me a json but it's actually blank...

```
$url = 'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion?locale=fr_FR&api_key=myprivateapikey';
$info_champion = $this->_curl_download($url);
print_r($info_champion);
```

Here is what the `curl_getinfo($ch)` return me :

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/euw/v1.2/champion?locale=fr_FR&api_key=mysecretapikey
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.391
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.219
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 52.8.176.206
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 192.168.1.104
    [local_port] => 57748
)
```

The link work in my browser so this is not the problem.

I don't understand what can be wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the URL being redirected somewhere else when the API is successful? In this case, you will need to follow that URL using curl.

Comment: No, the url is not redirected anywhere

Comment: Check whether you are able to connect to the host from the server where you are running your code

Comment: I can access it with a `file_get_contents`

Comment: Is that helper function or method of controller/library?

Comment: This is a function inside a controller

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when dealing with connections over `https` you need to add more parameters to the curl request and have a copy of `cacert.pem` available.

```
private function _curl_download($url){
    /* edit path to suit environment */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';

    /* download a copy from: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem */

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath( $cacert ) );
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://local.mywebsite.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RamRaider I've made a little search and I've found that I have to add this :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
```

and everything went right.